# Java - RMI Client side "NoSuchMethod" Problems

Tags: java, server, client, rmi

So I tried to programm an RMI server/client. The Server works just fine. But the Client however gives me this Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: stub class initialization failed
    at Addition_Stub.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.newFieldAccessor(UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newFieldAccessor(ReflectionFactory.java:140)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.acquireFieldAccessor(Field.java:1057)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.getFieldAccessor(Field.java:1038)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.getLong(Field.java:591)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getDeclaredSUID(ObjectStreamClass.java:1663)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.access$700(ObjectStreamClass.java:72)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:480)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:468)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.<init>(ObjectStreamClass.java:468)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(ObjectStreamClass.java:365)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:602)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1622)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1517)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.Naming.lookup(Naming.java:101)
    at AdditionClient.main(AdditionClient.java:8)
```

Client Code:

```
import java.rmi.*;

public class AdditionClient {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        AdditionInterface hello;
        try {
            System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());
            hello = (AdditionInterface)Naming.lookup("rmi://localhost/ABC");
            int result=hello.Add(9,10);
            System.out.println("Result is :"+result);

            }catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("HelloClient exception: " + e);
                }
        }
}
```

I am running the Server with the following VM Arguments:

```
-Djava.security.policy=file:${workspace_loc}/RMIClientSide/security.policy -Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:${workspace_loc}/RMIServerSide/bin/
```

My security.policy has the following content:

```
grant {
        permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

Addition Interface looks like this:

```
   import java.rmi.*;

   public interface AdditionInterface extends Remote {
       public int Add(int a,int b) throws RemoteException;
   }
```

------------- Server Side -----------:

AdditionServer:

```
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.server.*;   

public class AdditionServer {
       public static void main (String[] argv) {
           try {
               System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());

               Addition Hello = new Addition();                    
               Naming.rebind("rmi://localhost/ABC", Hello);

               System.out.println("Addition Server is ready.");
               }catch (Exception e) {
                   System.out.println("Addition Server failed: " + e);
                }
           }
}
```

AdditionInterface:

```
import java.rmi.*;

   public interface AdditionInterface extends Remote {
       public int add(int a,int b) throws RemoteException;

   }
```

Addition:

```
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.server.*;

public class Addition extends UnicastRemoteObject
         implements AdditionInterface {

      public Addition () throws RemoteException {   }

      public int add(int a, int b) throws RemoteException {
          int result=a+b;
          return result;
      }
 }
```

Comment: What does `AdditionInterface` look like?

Comment: added the AdditionInterface!

Comment: Can you show the server implementation of `AdditionInterface`?

Comment: added the whole Server code!

Comment: Have you changed the remote interface? And if so have you recompiled it and redeployed it and restarted the Registry and the server?

Comment: NB If you change the constructor of `Addition` to call `super(0);` you can get rid of the stub altogether: it will be generated dynamically. This is bound to solve your problem, whatever it is.